# How to redirect printed value of python script to the linux terminal as a command

Tags: python

```
from itertools import permutations
from itertools import combinations
import itertools
import random
import os
def split(arr, size):
     arrs = []
     while len(arr) > size:
         pice = arr[:size]
         arrs.append(pice)
         arr   = arr[size:]
     arrs.append(arr)
     return arrs
print("Enter the GCAP utility command:")
N=raw_input()
A= [N]
A1=[]
S7=[]
S6=[]
X=[]
X1=[]
m1=[]
G=0
A1=0
G1=[]
g1=[]
u=[]

def HELP():
   print('SYNTAX : ABC')

def comp():
    for x11, y11 in zip(Y, m1[G-1]):
        if x11 == y11:
            X1 = sorted(m1[G-1])
            A1= X1
    return A1

def my_containsAll(str1, Y):
    for c in Y:
        if c not in str1: return 0;
    return 1;

def mysplit(s):
    head = s.rstrip('0123456789')
    tail = s[len(head):]
    return head, tail

def imcon(u,U3):
     U1= ['imconfig','-i']
     U2=U1+u+U3
     return U2


if N == 'GCOA.01':     ## for first GCOA.01 command
    print("Enter the command in this format ")
    S=raw_input()
    print ("Enter the user interface for example : ")
    U= raw_input()
    for s in ['GCOA.01']:
              g = mysplit(s)
    g1.append('-c')
    g1.append(g[1])
    u.append(U)
    #print(g1)
    if S == "GCOA.01":   ## if no other parameter typed
        U4= imcon(u,g1)
        ss= ' '.join(U4)
        #print(ss)    
    else:
         S=S.split()
         S1 =[i.split('\t', 1)[0] for i in S] ## spliting the command into list
         #print(S1)
         G1= S1[0]
         #print(G1)
         for s in ['GCOA.01']:
              g = mysplit(s)
         #print(g[1])
         S11=S1[0]
         S5=[S11]
         del S1[0]
         for x in S1:   ## separate the parameters from the whole command
             print(x)
             X.append(x[:2])
         Y=list(X)
         S2=['-c','-a','-h']
         S12 =sorted(S2)
         str1 = ''.join(S12)
         #print(str1)
         A2= my_containsAll(str1, Y)
         if A2 == 1:
             #print(S2)
             S3=[]
             for i in range(1, len(S2)+1):    ## creating the permutation and combinations of the parameters
                  S3.extend(itertools.combinations(S2, i))
                  if i >= 1:
                       for k in S3:
                            for c in permutations(k):
                                 S6.append(c)
                            for l in S6:
                                 if l not in S7:
                                      S7.append(l)
            # print(S7)
             for m in S7:   ## creating the list of the different possible combination of P&C
                  m=list(m)
                  m1.append(m)
             #print (m1) 
             for i1 in m1:  ## for finding the index of the parameters given by the user from the P&C list of parameters
                  G=G+1
                  if Y == i1:
                          #print (G)
                          break;
             g1=g1+S1
             #print(g1)           
             if Y == m1[0]:
                  R=imcon(u,g1)
                  ss=' '.join(R)
                  print(ss)    ## this print are basically command which is to direct on terminal window
             elif Y == m1[1]:
                  R=imcon(u,g1)
                  ss=' '.join(R)
                  print(ss)

         else:
            HELP()
```

Output :
 imconfig -i th0 -c 01 -h -a

example: (in command prompt)

```
c:/python34> python ssm9.py
 imconfig -i th0 -c 01 - h -a

c:/python34> imconfig -i th0 -c 01 -h -a 
/// i want something like that means the above printed value redirect here. but in linux terminal window
```

Answer (score 0):

```
`python ssm9.py`
```

or

```
$(python ssm9.py)
```

or

```
eval `python ssm9.py`
```

or

```
eval $(python ssm9.py)
```

Should all work.

(You can try it like this:)

```
> $(echo "echo test")
test
```

Comment: S0III0s ---  i am getting the same string again.. i want that the line 'imconfig -i th0 -c 01 -h -a' goes to command line and return value from this imconfig file. As if we are entering direct command on the command line. Right now, eval function does not returning any result...

Comment: But... eval executes commands you pass to it as parameters, like in my example. What shell are you using?

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a sample code like this

```
vivek@vivekUbuntu:~$ cat sample.py
#! /usr/bin/python
import socket
hostname = socket.gethostname()

def getPingCommand(host):
    return "ping %s" %host

print getPingCommand(hostname)
```

And then executed like this:

```
vivek@vivekUbuntu:~$ `python sample.py`
PING vivekUbuntu (127.0.1.1) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from vivekUbuntu (127.0.1.1): icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=0.020 ms
64 bytes from vivekUbuntu (127.0.1.1): icmp_seq=2 ttl=64 time=0.027 ms
64 bytes from vivekUbuntu (127.0.1.1): icmp_seq=3 ttl=64 time=0.050 ms
64 bytes from vivekUbuntu (127.0.1.1): icmp_seq=4 ttl=64 time=0.050 ms
64 bytes from vivekUbuntu (127.0.1.1): icmp_seq=5 ttl=64 time=0.049 ms
^C
--- vivekUbuntu ping statistics ---
5 packets transmitted, 5 received, 0% packet loss, time 4007ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 0.020/0.039/0.050/0.013 ms
vivek@vivekUbuntu:~$
```

Even the option mentioned by S0III0s is also correct. It works for me.

Comment: 'imconfig' is a executable file and in code it's simple string. so is it possible somehow 'imconfig -i eth0...'  which is a string, will call that executable imconfig file. How should i make my approach???????

Comment: @SDSM: Ensure that, your python code prints the desired imconfig command. Then your code will work.

Comment: My code prints the desired command. But how machine would know that its an executable file? since according to code it is a simple string.

Comment: abcd@sdkr :\opt\devkit\target\root\ python ssm9.py                                                              imconfig -i th0 -c 01 - h -a    ## here it is string
See this is i am getting when i run the code. So is it possible somehow we can do like this (only prob is i don't how i redirect this imconfig line)
abcd@sdkr :\opt\devkit\target\root\ imconfig -i th0 -c 01 -h -a

Comment: Machine can only run this binary i.e imconfig  provided you are calling from the absolute path of the binary, with an executable permission. Say for example if `imconfig` binary file is there in `/opt/devkit/target/root` then the python output code should return the string like `/opt/devkit/target/root/imconfig  -i th0 -c 01 -h -a` (Assuming  `-i th0 -c 01 -h -a` are the parameters.)